# How can I continue to receive console information sent via NSLog() after I push an app into the background?

Tags: iphone, xcode

When debugging crashes and errors, the NSLog() function is incredibly useful, even vital.

Unfortunately, some errors can provoked by pushing an app to the background, and that same act 'cuts' the ability to receive NSLog info, which makes debugging crashes related to moving an app into the background very difficult.  How can I get NSLog info after moving the program to the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app still pushes log statements to the console if your app is running in the background.  If your app is not running but is suspended, there is nothing to log anyway.

Comment: I haven't received any error messages when returning to the foreground caused a crash -- is there some lag before the console starts reporting again?  (When I tracked it down, the error was of a type that should have produced a console output)

Comment: I take it that since you marked the answer correct you got it figured out.

Comment: Yeah, if I remember correctly it turned out to be related to a simulator bug or something equally stupid.